# How to initialize vector with non ininitialization-list constructor in class member default value;

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, initializer-list

As demonstrated in code below, I want to initialize the vector member by calling `constructors` , I know some initilziation methods allow me to achieve this, but I wanna make my code more clear by calling them in the member declaration field.

Though it's possible, I have
to write `more codes`. So, if there are other expressions can fit my requirement with less codes. In another word, can I ignore the constructor with the initialization-list as the paramter.

```cpp
struct A {
    vector<int> vs{10, 1}; // call initializer list
};

// what i want is: 1 1 1 1 1 ...
struct B {
    vector<int> vs {vector<int>(10, 1)}; // ok, but too much codes
    vector<int> vs1 = vector<int>(10, 1);
    vector<int> vs2;
    B() : vs2(10, 1) {} // ok, but i'd like to put it in declaration
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "easy" way here.  Uniform initialization isn't really uniform since the old interface wasn't written in a way to support braced initialization because that wasn't a thing before C++11.  I personally prefer `vector<int> vs1 = vector<int>(10, 1);` but that's just me.

Comment: I would say those initializations are holy mess.

Comment: Yep.  If you'd like confirmation, see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs